# visual studio express 2012 and cmake

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, visual-studio-2012

I am looking for a way to compile some libraries which come ready to be used through cmake, the problem is that I would like to use VC++ express 2012 (the first express version to allow x64 development) however when I run cmake I keep getting this:

```
CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Visual Studio 11".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file:C:/Users/Alexander Rojas/workspace/jthread-1.3.1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeCCompiler.cmake
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file:C:/Users/Alexander Rojas/workspace/jthread-1.3.1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeCXXCompiler.cmake
Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I found that this path is the path to devenv.exe but this brand new vc doesn't have this program. Any ideas for a workaround?

Comment: http://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=13348

Comment: Yes, I saw that, however they don't offer a workaround

Comment: can't you let cmake generate a vcxproj file for VS2012 or VC Express 2010 or so, then build it manually (using devenv or msbuild or the IDE)?

Comment: In the paid Visual Studio applications CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is either the devenv.com or MSbuild.exe. I believe MSBuild.exe does not work with express versions so if this is stopping the build you may have to wait for a fix.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So, in the file `CMakeVS11FindMake.cmake` I had to change all references of the registry key

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\VisualStudio\\11.0
```

to the key

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\Microsoft\\WDExpress\\11.0_Config
```

(just adding them as an extra hint will work)

Answer (score 5):

Visual Studio 2012 Express Edition is not currently supported in any released version of CMake (2.8.9). However CMake developers have just today [checked in code to fix the problem](http://www.cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=13348). The fix should be in CMake 2.8.10 whenever it's released.

If you really need it sooner you should be able to grab [a nightly CMake installer](http://www.cmake.org/files/dev/), but you may need to way until the 20120919 installers are posted since I'm not sure whether this fix made it into the 20120918 installers.

(To test it out today, I checked out the source code from their [git repository](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Git), switched to branch "next", configured with an old CMake, built myself a fresh CMake, and confirmed that it works fine VS 2012 Express.)

Comment: does it also support building for ARM?

Answer (score 2):

I still needed to apply Sambatyon's fix above to CMakeVS11FindMake.cmake, and I'm using CMake 2.8.10.2.

Answer (score 0):

The other solutions don't work anymore; with the latest (express 2012 for desktop as of writing) you may need to modify:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake 2.8\share\cmake-2.8\Modules\CMakeVS12FindMake.cmake
```

To read something like:

```
#=============================================================================
# Copyright 2007-2013 Kitware, Inc.
#
# Distributed under the OSI-approved BSD License (the "License");
# see accompanying file Copyright.txt for details.
#
# This software is distributed WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the
# implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
# See the License for more information.
#=============================================================================
# (To distribute this file outside of CMake, substitute the full
#  License text for the above reference.)

# Always use MSBuild because:
# - devenv treats command-line builds as recently-loaded projects in the IDE
# - devenv does not appear to support non-standard platform toolsets
# If we need devenv for Intel Fortran in the future we should add
# a special case when Fortran is enabled.
find_program(CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM
  NAMES MSBuild
  HINTS "[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\MSBuild\\ToolsVersions\\4.0;MSBuildToolsPath]" <--- Change this line.
  )
message("Found: ${CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM}")

mark_as_advanced(CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM)
set(MSVC12 1)
set(MSVC_VERSION 1800)
```

This is for cmake 2.8.11.2

Edit: Note specifically this is with regard to the VS2012 bundle, not the VS2013 release candidate, or future version of VS2013, where the correct ToolsVersions is \12.0

Answer (score -1):

My work around: generate for 2010, "Reload All" in VS2012 and then "Update VC++ Projects" on the solution in solution explorer.

However: My install comprises active VS 2010, expired VS 2012 trial, active VS 2012 Express.