# CMake Version > 3 and Visual Studio 2012 Express: No Compiler found

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, express, cmake

I try to use CMake(Version 3.2.0) with VS 2012 Express, but whenever I start the process, the following error occurs:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
  No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
  No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.
```

I tried the solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12434696/visual-studio-express-2012-and-cmake), but the file "CMakeVS11FindMake.cmake"(or CMakeVS12FindMake.cmake), does not exist in the CMake-directory.

Maybe someone knows a solution, that will work for me?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How did you invoke CMake? From inside of Visual Studio? Or did you use the command line? In the latter case, you have to load the variables using `vsvars32.bat` which you can find somewhere in your VS install directory.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I used the command line but already solved the problem by reinstalling VS 2012. It seems that there just has been a failure during the installation.